# Parse JSON DateTime object to local time in JQuery by ignoring timezone

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, angularjs, momentjs

I am facing an issue while parsing JSON Date Time object using moment(of course I tried many approaches suggested in Stackoverflow but nothing worked in my case).

In my application, I'm storing a DateTime value as UTC DateTime. Now when I'm displaying I need to display it according to the browser timezone. After going through many StackOverflow questions, I used "moment.js" as below

```
//From server, the Date object looks like /Date(1506510057813)/ 
//The equivalent DateTime value stored in Database is 2017-09-27 13:00:57.813
fuction DateTimeFormatter(value)
{    
    if (value != undefined) {
        var newValue = new Date(moment.utc(value));

        //But at this line, even with just moment(value) all I am getting is DateTime which is not same as UTC time.
        //I don't want any time zone to get appended all I want is just 13:00:57

        var newHours = newValue.getHours() - newValue.getTimezoneOffset() / 60;
        var newMinutes = (newHours + '.0').split('.')[1] * 6;

        newValue.setHours(newHours);
        newValue.setMinutes(newMinutes);

        return moment(newValue).format(applicationTableDateFormat);
    } 
    else
        return "";
}
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong or is there any other way I can display time as per browser time zone.

Comment: Is there anyhow you change the format from server to a standard date like ISO `2017-09-27T18:39:03.076Z`? So that you wouldn't even had to parse the date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have a UTC moment, you can convert it to local.

```
moment.utc(value).local().format(...)
```

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/local/

But it sounds like maybe your real problem is when you store the date. If you're storing it as UTC, make sure you actually convert the local value to UTC before you store it. That way when you read it, you get a predictable value that you can safely convert to any locale.

Comment: I am storing it has UTC time only.

Answer (score 0):

Angularjs has its own mechanism to display formatted dates on views you just needs an absolute representation of a date and it takes care of the rest. And by absolute, I mean, a `Date` which is settled in a timezone whether it's utc or not, you need to know what timezone you are talking about.

### [The `date` filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)

It's a filter from the core module of angularjs and it accepts:

> *"... either as Date object, milliseconds (string or number) or various ISO 8601 datetime string formats (e.g. yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.sssZ and its shorter versions like yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mmZ, yyyy-MM-dd or yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ). If no timezone is specified in the string input, the time is considered to be in the local timezone."* ([Angularjs date filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date))

### The problem

Angularjs need a proper date input in order to display it correctly, in your case you seem to have the milliseconds format (sort of, `/Date(1506510057813)/`), you could use that and extract the numeric part and input that on the pipe, or you can change the server to send the ISO 8601 date (a.k.a., `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.sssZ`).

For example:

```
let rawDate = '/Date(1506510057813)/';
let re = /\/Date\((\d+)\)\//g; // regex to extract number from the string date

let myDate = new Date(Number(re.exec()[1])) // extract the milliseconds
```

Or

```
let rawDate = '2017-09-27T11:00:57.813Z'; 
let myDate  = new Date(rawDate)// and you don't need to do anything else
```

Either way you'd end up with something like this:

```
<span> {{ myDate | date }}</span>
```